# Confusion about django.shortcuts.render() method signature in 1.10

Tags: python, django, dictionary

The Django 1.10 release notes (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10) say:

- The dictionary and context_instance parameters for the following functions are removed:

  - `django.shortcuts.render()`
  - ...

However, the documentation for `render()` in 1.10 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) still lists `context` as an argument of type `dictionary`:

#### context

A dictionary of values to add to the template context. By default, this is an empty dictionary. If a value in the dictionary is callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.

---

My question, to put it frankly, is what gives? Normally this would be an academic question, but the following code:

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request, {})
    return render(request, 'maintenance/maintenance.html', context)
```

yields this error:

```
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

and this was the best lead I could find as to what the problem might be. I should also mention that this error appeared after updating Django from 1.8 to 1.10.

Comment: The signature of the first 3 arguments has not changed. An optional keyword-argument called `context_instance` is what was dropped. Can you (1.) provide the full traceback, and (2.) ensure that your `render` there is actually `django.shortcuts.render`? PS I think it creates a `RequestContext` for you.

Comment: Don't you need to provide something within the curly brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing `context` and `context_instance`, which are two separate arguments. The `context_instance` argument has been removed in Django 1.10, but `context` remains.

As the docs say, `context` should be a *dictionary* of values. You are getting the error because you are passing a `RequestContext` instance instead of a dictionary. You can fix your example view by changing it to:

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'maintenance/maintenance.html', context)
```